# Spring: How to inject any one of 4 beans into another bean

Tags: java, spring

I have an object `Bar` which requires object `Foo` for its constructor (where `Foo` is an interface type).  Both `Bar` and `Foo` are beans.

I would like to `@Autowire` a `Bar`, and define in the annotation which `Foo` to use, without having creating a different `@Bean` for each type of `Foo`.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public BarClass getBarClass(){
        return new BarClass(fooObject);//Where do I get this object from?
    }
    ...more BarClass beans...
    @Bean(name = "type1")
    public FooClass getFooClass1(){
        return new ConcreteFooClass();
    }
    @Bean(name = "type2")
    public FooClass getFooClass2(){
        return new SecondConcreteFooClass();
    }
    ...more FooClass beans...
}

@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
public class myClass {
    @Autowire
    BarClass b;//Somehow define here that you are supposed to use "type1" Foo to construct this BarClass
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have to use @Qualifier http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html

Comment: @Evgeny I have to use `@Qualifier` if I want to get a `FooClass`.  I expect `@Qualifier` to come in somewhere in this answer, but that's not the only thing required.

Comment: You have your foos and bars mixed up, but just use qualifier, what's the prob.

Comment: @NimChimpsky Note that Bar requires a Foo to be instantiated.  I need to tell Spring *which* Foo to use, but I want a Bar, not a Foo.

Comment: Just autowire with qualifier

Comment: I think I understand... You want to specify which food to be injected every time a Bar is created. Take a look at the factory pattern http://www.skorks.com/2008/10/are-you-using-the-full-power-of-spring-when-injecting-your-dependencies/

Comment: @Evgeny, thanks for the link.  I see how they passed in a value to the function using XML, and I'm not against making `FooClass` come from a `FactoryBean`.  However, I have no idea how to do that via annotations, and I also don't know how to tell `BarClass` which `FooClass` to pass into the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it's not tested ...

```
 public class BarFactory
    {   
       public static Bar createBar(Foo foo)
       {
          Bar bar= new Bar();
          bar.setFoo(foo);
          return bar;
       }
    }

<bean id="bar1" class="my.company.BarFactory"
                          factory-method="createBar">
    <constructor-arg ref="foo1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bar2" class="my.company.BarFactory"
                          factory-method="createBar">
    <constructor-arg ref="foo2"/>
</bean>
```

Java Config:

```
@Configuration
public class Conf {

   //define foo1 and 2

    @Bean
    public Bar getBar1() {
        return BarFactory.createBar(foo1)
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar getBar2() {
        return BarFactory.createBar(foo2)
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't use any XML...is it possible to do this without XML?

Comment: I would also like to be able to do this without defining a different bar for each foo.

Comment: I updated the answer. This way you can have only one class Bar, just 2 spring beans of this type.

Comment: I noticed, thank you, and that code works.  My problem is that I have 4 different `Foo`s and nearly 20 `Bar`s (and rising).  This means that for each `Bar`, I have to write 4 more `@Bean`s.  I would like to remove that code duplication is possible.

Comment: That don't look to me like a code duplication. You have all the logic for creating a bean on one place(the createBar method), you just have to define how to use it when new foo is introduced. If the Bars don't have to be a spring beans just use the factory pattern outside the spring context, bu be careful, you will loose the ability to autowire in them, use declarative transactions and so on, whitch you may need in future...

Comment: It's the duplication of creating 80 different functions that are very similar, simply passing in a different foo into a different bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can,t do this without specifying a qualifier on bar class. But that should not be a problem have two bars with qualifiers, which have there relevant constructor args

Comment: I don't want to have to create a different method for each type of `Bar` with a different `Foo` put in the constructor.  (I have 4 different types of `Foo`, and nearly 20 different types of `Bar`s...which means I would need to create 80 different methods).  I would prefer to tell Spring which `Foo` to use to construct `Bar` in the annotations in `myClass`

Comment: Do they have to be spring managed beans, just use factory if not.